# County lines in ggplot map and plot colors

Tags: r, maps

I'm trying to create a map of my data in R. When the map is created, no outlines show and the fill of the points isn't showing either. The map of Virginia is made using Rs map_data function. When the map pulls up, it's just black with no county lines. I've tried changing the polygon "color" to "col" and "fill". No change. Additionally, the data points on the map are black as well- no color, despite my code. Is there there a mistake in my code?

Here is a sample of my dataset

| urban_continuum | p.shannon | p.simpson | latitude | longitude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A_Rural | 4.609 | 0.9334 | 37.7659 | -75.7578 |
| C_Suburb | 6.420 | 0.9973 | 38.0241 | -78.5535 |
| D_City | 5.961 | 0.9959 | 38.8183 | -77.0820 |
| B_Town | 5.033 | 0.9923 | 37.7879 | -80.0086 |

Here's my code:

```
Virginia=map_data("state", region = "virginia")

VA.pdiv=ggplot()+
  geom_polygon(data=Virginia, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group,
               color="white"))+
  geom_point(data = VA.county1, aes(x=longitude, y=latitude,
                                    fill=p.shannon,
                                    size=p.simpson,
                                    shape=urban_continuum))+
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "blue", high = "orange")+
  labs(x="Longitude", y="Latitude",
       fill="Shannon Diversity Index of VA Plants",
       size="Simpson Diversity Index of VA Plants",
       title = "Plant Diversity in Virginia")+
  coord_map()
VA.pdiv
```

When I tried suggestions from others, I got color points but still no county lines. I'll remove either p.simpson or p.shannon to help with clarity, but for now I'm just troubleshooting the county lines issue.
Here's my code:

```
require(ggplot2)
library(ggplot2)

#pull up our base map
Virginia= map_data("county", region="Virginia")

ggplot()+
  geom_polygon(data = Virginia, 
               aes(x = long, 
                   y = lat, 
                   group = group)) +
  geom_point(data = VA.county1, 
             aes(x = longitude, 
                 y = latitude,
                 color = p.shannon,
                 size=p.simpson,
                 shape = urban_continuum)) +
  scale_color_gradient(low = "blue", high = "orange") +
  labs(x = "Longitude", 
       y = "Latitude",
       color = "Shannon Diversity Index of VA Plants",
       size = "Simpson Diversity Index of VA Plants",
       shape= "Urban Continuum",
       title = "Plant Diversity in Virginia") +
  coord_map()
```

Here's the resulting plot:
[image]

Comment: Could you add some data for `VA.county1` to make the code reproducible? thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My apologies. I've added some sample data, as well as some clarifying details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the county lines in the state, you may want to use "county" instead of "state" with `map_data`.

For `geom_polygon` there is no need for `color`, unless you want to give different counties different colors (in which case you could consider `fill`, as I would suggest using `color` with your points).

For `geom_point` I switched to `color` and changed to `scale_color_gradient` to match.

Let me know if this is closer to what you had in mind.

```
library(ggplot2)

Virginia <- map_data("county", region = "virginia")

ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = Virginia, 
               aes(x = long, 
                   y = lat, 
                   group = group)) +
  geom_point(data = VA.county1, 
             aes(x = longitude, 
                 y = latitude,
                 color = p.shannon,
                 size = p.simpson,
                 shape = urban_continuum)) +
  scale_color_gradient(low = "blue", high = "orange") +
  labs(x = "Longitude", 
       y = "Latitude",
       fill = "Shannon Diversity Index of VA Plants",
       size = "Simpson Diversity Index of VA Plants",
       title = "Plant Diversity in Virginia") +
  coord_map()
```

**Map**

[image: map of counties in virginia with color points]

**Data**

```
VA.county1 <- structure(list(urban_continuum = c("A_Rural", "C_Suburb", "D_City", 
"B_Town"), p.shannon = c(4.609, 6.42, 5.961, 5.033), p.simpson = c(0.9334, 
0.9973, 0.9959, 0.9923), latitude = c(37.7659, 38.0241, 38.8183, 
37.7879), longitude = c(-75.7578, -78.5535, -77.082, -80.0086
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: This solution worked for the points, thank you so much! weirdly, for the county lines I still can't get it to work on my end.

Comment: What happens are your end? No county lines like above? Did you use the exact same code? Did you use "county" instead of "state" in `map_data`?

Comment: No county lines like above. Exact same code- I copy and pasted yours into my system. I'll edit/update my question to show what I've done.

Comment: @madam_fledershrew If you don't add any layers and just do `ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = Virginia, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) + coord_map()` what do you get? And what version of `ggplot2` are you using? Have you also tried clearing your environment and restarting R?

Comment: Just went to my updates, and updated everything. ggplot version 3.3.5. Cleared global environment, restarted R. No luck. I copy and pasted your code into my script- still no lines.

Comment: @madam_fledershrew This is very strange...what if you load up state and county data: `states <- map_data("state"); va_df <- subset(states, region == "virginia"); counties <- map_data("county"); va_county <- subset(counties, region == "virginia")` then can you try: `ggplot(data = va_df, mapping = aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) + geom_polygon(data = va_county) + coord_map()`? This also works at my end, and closer to what I have used in the past.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this example with California counties [here](https://eriqande.github.io/rep-res-web/lectures/making-maps-with-R.html)?

Comment: Or perhaps trying this `ggplot(data = Virginia, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) + geom_polygon(color = "white") + coord_map()` to emphasize county lines?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response! The California solution worked!!!!!! Thank you so much!